# Why do i get an error message in my switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to write a program that, well i cant explain it but you can see it yourself but there's a Problem. Every case in the switch statement has an error message.

```
public class Main {
    
    static int keyZero;
    static int keyOne;
    static int keyTwo;
    static int keyThree;
    static int keyFour;
    static int keyFive;
    static int keySix;
    static int keySeven;
    static int keyEight;
    static int keyNine;
    
    static int currentFirstNumber = keyZero;
    static int currentMiddleNumber = keyZero;
    static int currentLastNumber = keyZero;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        
        
        keyZero = KeyEvent.VK_0;
        keyOne = KeyEvent.VK_1;
        keyTwo = KeyEvent.VK_2;
        keyThree = KeyEvent.VK_3;
        keyFour = KeyEvent.VK_4;
        keyFive = KeyEvent.VK_5;
        keySix = KeyEvent.VK_6;
        keySeven = KeyEvent.VK_7;
        keyEight = KeyEvent.VK_8;
        keyNine = KeyEvent.VK_9;
        
        int currentFirstNumber = keyZero;
    
    public static void upFirstNumber()
    {
        switch(currentFirstNumber) {
            case keyZero:
                currentFirstNumber = keyOne;
                break;
            case keyOne:
                currentFirstNumber = keyTwo;
                break;
            case keyTwo:
                currentFirstNumber = keyTwo;
                break;
            case keyThree:
                currentFirstNumber = keyTwo;
                break;
            case keyFour:
                currentFirstNumber = keyTwo;
                break;
            case keyFive:
                currentFirstNumber = keyTwo;
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Following error message is the message i get, when i hover over it.
 `case expression must be constant expressions`
Please help

Comment: `keyZero` (and friends) is not a [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). That's all.

Comment: What do you mean by that? How can i fix it?

Comment: Make them `static final int keyTwo = KeyEvent.VK_2;` etc.  to make the constant expressions.

Comment: Also fix your bracket situation in your post (and your program as well?). 
Right now it looks like you are defining a method inside of the main method.